# Can I specify the table when using sequelize.col?

Tags: sequelize.js

My query looks something like

```
({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('id')), 'commitCount']],
  include: [
    {
      model: global.mysqlDb.Commit,
      attributes: ['id'],
      where: {
        RepositoryId: req.params.repositoryId
      }
    }, {
      model: global.mysqlDb.SourceFile
    }
  ],
  group: ['SourceFileId']
});
```

But the `id` in the `sequelize.col` is ambiguous because it could be from any of the tables. Any way for me to specify the table name as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do `sequelize.col('table.column')` and then it will automatically be quoted

Comment: Do I use plural or singular `table` name?

Comment: Depending on whether your table name is pluralized or not :). Since it's just a string, sequelize will not change the casing

Comment: I had to pass the model name that I used with `sequelize.define` (not the table name) for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize uses the lower case  model name as the alias for your table name in your generated SQL query. If you have a model `Commit` and a table `commits`, for example, the fully qualified column name should be `sequelize.col('commit.id')`.

*Note that commit is singular*